# Accessing Selected Index of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm attempting to access a list called people and I'm matching up the index of the listitem selected to the index of my list so that I can print the surname of the person to a textbox.
I have this code:

```
surnameTxtBox.Text = people[listBoxNames.SelectedItems[0].Index].Surname;
```

listBoxNames is the name of my ListBox but for some reason, visual studio tells me that there's no definition called index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SelectedIndex` instead to get the SelectedItem index:

```
surnameTxtBox.Text = people[listBoxNames.SelectedIndex].Surname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're simply binding to a list of your own objects (I'll assume it's named "Person") to the `ListBox`, you can get the object directly from `SelectedItems`:

```
surnameTxtBox.Text = ((Person)listBoxNames.SelectedItems[0]).Surname;
```

Or `SelectedItem`:

```
surnameTxtBox.Text = ((Person)listBoxNames.SelectedItem).Surname;
```